# How do I view a lightning application I deployed using SFDX?

Tags: salesforcedx, aura, lightning-apps

I am trying to deploy a very simple Hello World application and view it in my scratch Org.
In VSCode using the Salesforce Extension Pack, I've created an Aura App. In the MyAuraApp.app file I added this:

```
<aura:application>
    <c:MyAuraComponent/>
</aura:application>
```

Then I created an Aura Component. The MyAuraComponent.cmp file looks like this:

```
<aura:component>
    Hello, world!
</aura:component>
```

Then I deployed this application to a scratch Org. I would like to now go into the Org and view 'Hello World' but I can't figure out how to do so.

I can see that the Component bundle is in the Org through the Lightning Components Page:

[image: Components Page]

However, when I go to the App Launcher or the App Manager it is nowhere to be found. I am logged in as a System Administrator. I don't believe this would be a permissions issue. Is there something else that needs to be done in order to access this app?

Comment: Why are you using Aura? This has been superseded by LWC, which is easier to develop and performs better at runtime.

Comment: I suspect you simply need to ensure the user has access to the Lightning App, so it will appear in the app launcher (waffle).

Comment: Because I'm developing security scanning rules for Aura applications that already exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can preview your aura component using the developer console. Follow the below steps:

- Click on the **gear** icon.
- Then Click on the **Developer Console**.
- In the developer console click on the **File** > **Open Lightning Resources**
- Click on your **MyAuraApp** app and click on the **Open Selected**.
- Once the app opens in the console, click on the **preview** button.
  [image]

You can also add an aura component to the tab. for that follow this step:

- The `force:appHostable` interface needs to be implemented so that you can use your aura component as Tab like custom object.

  `<aura:component implements="force:appHostable"> <p> Hello, world! </p> </aura:component>`
- From **Setup**, in the Quick Find box, enter **Tabs**, and then select **Tabs**.
- Click New in the **Lightning Component Tabs** related list.
- Select the **aura component** to appear in the **Lightning Component**.
- Add tab **label**, **name** and **style**, then click on **next**.
- Choose the user profiles that you want to have access to the new custom tab.
- Click on **save**.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer but is there anyway to view the whole app instead of just a single component? I would not like to use preview mode. I would like it to actually be accessible as a real app.

Comment: @user3632719, Check if this may help you. - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/lightning_out.htm